# postgres similar to pandas melt, date between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

df

```
created_at invoice_no period_start  period_end  nett 
2021-09-01   A          2021-09-01  2022-08-31  120€
2021-12-01   B          2022-01-01  2022-06-30  120€
```

Expected output

```
invoice_month  invoice_no nett_per_month
2021-09-01     A                10€
2021-10-01     A                10€
2021-11-01     A                10€
2021-12-01     A                10€
....
2022-08-01     A                10€

....
2021-12-01     B               null
2022-01-01     B                20€
2022-02-01     B                20€
2022-03-01     B                20€
....
2022-06-01     B                20€
```

Based on df, I would like to transform df into the expected output.
I believe that a similar approach is possible using pandas melt (in Python).
I can think of the logic to do it, but not sure about the code.

1. Use a cross join to another table so that we have a column that consists of all the months
2. If the month column is between period start and period end, divide the nett column by the number of months in between period start and period end.
   If the period start or period end is null, take the created_at as the invoice_month.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the the output with CTE Query with left outer join

generate_series will generate the first of every month within the given dates

```
WITH monthly_bill AS (
 select
 invoice_no,
 generate_series(created_at::date,
 
case when period_start is not null and period_end is not null then
period_end 
when period_start is null then
coalesce(period_start,created_at)
when period_end is null then
coalesce(period_end,created_at)
end::date 
 
 ,  '1 month'::interval)::date as billdt,
  case when period_start is not null and period_end is not null then
   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM AGE(period_end,period_start)) * 12 + 
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM AGE(period_end,period_start)) +1
  end as totmnth 
from tablename 
)
SELECT mb.invoice_no,mb.billdt,totmnth,case when period_start is not null and period_end is not null then
      case when billdt<period_start then
              null
              else

              nett/totmnth
              end
              when period_start is null or period_end is null then
              nett
end::int as billamt

FROM monthly_bill mb left outer join tablename tb on tb.invoice_no=mb.invoice_no
```

Table Data

```
CREATE TABLE tableName 
(
    created_at date,    invoice_no  varchar(300),    period_start date,   period_end    date,    nett   int
);

INSERT INTO tableName (created_at,invoice_no,period_start,period_end,nett) VALUES ('1-Sep-2021', 'A', '1-Sep-2021', '31-Aug-2022', '120');
INSERT INTO tableName (created_at,invoice_no,period_start,period_end,nett) VALUES ('1-Dec-2021', 'B', '1-Jan-2022', '30-Jun-2022', '120');
INSERT INTO tableName (created_at,invoice_no,period_start,period_end,nett) VALUES ('1-Dec-2021', 'C', '1-Jan-2022', '30-Jan-2022', '12');
INSERT INTO tableName (created_at,invoice_no,period_start,period_end,nett) VALUES ('1-Dec-2021', 'D', null, null, '15');
INSERT INTO tableName (created_at,invoice_no,period_start,period_end,nett) VALUES ('1-Dec-2021', 'E', '1-Jan-2022', null, '6');
INSERT INTO tableName (created_at,invoice_no,period_start,period_end,nett) VALUES ('1-Dec-2020', 'F', null, '1-Jan-2022', '7');
select * from tableName;
```

OUtput :

```
invoice_no  billdt  totmnth     billamt
A   2021-09-01  12  10
A   2021-10-01  12  10
A   2021-11-01  12  10
A   2021-12-01  12  10
A   2022-01-01  12  10
A   2022-02-01  12  10
A   2022-03-01  12  10
A   2022-04-01  12  10
A   2022-05-01  12  10
A   2022-06-01  12  10
A   2022-07-01  12  10
A   2022-08-01  12  10
B   2021-12-01  6   null
B   2022-01-01  6   20
B   2022-02-01  6   20
B   2022-03-01  6   20
B   2022-04-01  6   20
B   2022-05-01  6   20
B   2022-06-01  6   20
C   2021-12-01  1   null
C   2022-01-01  1   12
D   2021-12-01      15
E   2021-12-01      6
F   2020-12-01      7
24 rows
```